# Switch to a program on Linux Debian

Tags: c#, linux, mono, debian, cron

I have developed a program in C# using mono toolkit.
The program works like a charm on my Linux Debian VPS.

I need this program to run constantly and I execute it via a crontab.
The process is effectively running in the background. 
However, I am not able to "show" in my putty terminal what the program writes when I execute it directly in the console for example.

So I wonder how I can switch to the process and show these data?

Thank you very much,
Joey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the output of a program running in the background, first get its PID with the command `pidof program_name`. This will return, for example, 2518.

Now you can run `tail -f /proc/2518/fd/1` to follow the output of that program.